# Symbolic Math in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

infixl 4 :+:, :-: 
infixl 5 :*:, :/:

data Expr a  = Const a 
         | (Expr a) :+: (Expr a) 
         | (Expr a) :-: (Expr a)
         | (Expr a) :*: (Expr a)
         | (Expr a) :/: (Expr a)
         deriving (Show, Eq)

evalExpr (Const a) = a 
evalExpr (a :+: b) = liftM2 (+) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :-: b) = liftM2 (-) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :*: b) = liftM2 (*) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :/: b) = if (evalExpr b) == 0 
        then Nothing 
         else liftM2 (/) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
```

This is my symbolic representation of math and an evaluation function. I have a problem with my limited knowledge of monads and the maybe type this problem arises with me wanting to return a nothing value if there is a division by zero in my evaluation function. For many different reasons when I try to run `evalExpr (Const 3)` or anything more complicated it fails on runtime. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What type do you think `evalExpr` should have?  What type does it actually have (ask GHCi via `:type`)?  Does that explain some of the issues to you?

Comment: The `Const` case of `evalExpr` should say `return a`.

Comment: Yes I tried using :t and I got what I expected the type to be (Num (Maybe a)) => Expr a -> Maybe a in otherwords it takes an expression with a maybe number and returns a maybe number

Comment: Well if you avoid requiring `Num (Maybe a)` and instead make the two modifications required for to reduce the constraint to `Num a` then things flow quite smoothly.  Not sure what instance of `Num (Maybe a)` you are using, seeing as you have not posted any such code.

Comment: @KyleMcKean I think you might instead want `Num a => Expr a -> Maybe a`, otherwise you'd end up with something equivalent to `Expr a -> Maybe (Maybe a)`, with `Maybe a` being an instance of `Num`.

Comment: Declaring the type to what @bheklilr said only leaves the code with one parse error in the IF statement

Comment: @KyleMcKean So use consistent indentation.  You also won't get away with just `Num` as your constraint because you're using `/`, you'll have to change it to a more specific type class that works for `/`, since `Num` does not.

Comment: After I changed to a fractional type it said it could not dedcue the type due to the literal 0

Comment: I am sorry i am such a noob at haskell..... the error messages are very unforgiving

Comment: @KyleMcKean `evalExpr b` is going to return a `Maybe a`, not an `a`, so you could do `if evalExpr b == Just 0`, otherwise you're trying to compare a number to something that isn't a number.

Comment: Thank you so much @bheklilr you were so helpful and everything is working now

Answer (score 3):

The version I think you want is:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

infixl 4 :+:, :-: 
infixl 5 :*:, :/:

data Expr a  = Const a 
         | (Expr a) :+: (Expr a) 
         | (Expr a) :-: (Expr a)
         | (Expr a) :*: (Expr a)
         | (Expr a) :/: (Expr a)
         deriving (Show, Eq)

evalExpr :: (Eq a, Num a, Fractional a) => (Expr a) -> Maybe a
evalExpr (Const a) = return a 
evalExpr (a :+: b) = liftM2 (+) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :-: b) = liftM2 (-) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :*: b) = liftM2 (*) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :/: b) = if (evalExpr b) == return 0
        then Nothing 
        else liftM2 (/) (evalExpr a) (evalExpr b)
```

The changes are using the correct monadic (in this case `Maybe`) type in the `Const` case (`return a` instead of `a`) and when you check for 0 (`if (evalExpr b) == return 0` rather than `if (evalExpr b) == 0`).

(Not that both could have used `Just` rather than `return` because it is definitely the Maybe monad we are using.)

By fixing the type of `evalExpr` I was able to work out where the problems were much more easily. The use of liftM2 makes the Haskell expressions quite general, hence the many different versions of this that either compiled and didn't work as expected or failed to compile with confusing messages. Once the type was fixed the compiler told me straight away it was the `Const` case and the `==` expression that were causing problems.

You may also be interested in using the applicative functions `<$>` and `<*>` instead of `liftM2`, as these can be used no matter how many arguments there are:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

...

evalExpr :: (Eq a, Num a, Fractional a) => (Expr a) -> Maybe a
evalExpr (Const a) = return a 
evalExpr (a :+: b) = (+) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :-: b) = (-) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :*: b) = (*) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :/: b) = if (evalExpr b) == return 0
        then Nothing 
        else (/) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
```

If you want to lift a function of three arguments, `triad` say, then it is

```
triad <$> arg1 <*> arg2 <*> arg3
```

Look up applicative functors for more info. There is a good description [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

**Update**

@gallais made a point about the style of the division case. I wasn't going to mention it in the interests of clarity, but this is probably how I would do it:

```
evalExpr :: (Eq a, Num a, Fractional a) => (Expr a) -> Maybe a
evalExpr (Const a) = return a 
evalExpr (a :+: b) = (+) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :-: b) = (-) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :*: b) = (*) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (evalExpr b)
evalExpr (a :/: b) = (/) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (failOn 0 $ evalExpr b)

failOn x a = case a of
    Just x -> Nothing
    _      -> a
```

Or a more general version taking advantage of the `MonadZero` class and taking a function:

```
...
evalExpr (a :/: b) = (/) <$> (evalExpr a) <*> (failOn (==0) $ evalExpr b)

failOn f a = do
    b <- fmap f a
    if b then mzero else a
```

There are other monadic helper functions that are useful in cases like this, such as `guard`, `when` and `unless`, see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#g:6).

Comment: You may want to factor out `evalExpr b` in the last clause. A monadic style would be appropriate.